# JavaScript Timers and Page Navigation

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Hopefully a simple question; if I create a timer using JavaScript embedded within my page, and I then navigate away from that page, will the timer be automatically cancelled or will it continue to run?

**EDIT**

Expanding the question, if that page were to perform a post-back (in my case, this is ASP.NET Forms), and the script is rendered as a part of the page markup, would the original timer created when the form is first displayed be cancelled during that post-back or would a second timer be created?

Example (rough typed):

```
<body>
  ...
  <script type='text/javascript'>
    function doSomething() { ... }
    x = setInterval(doSomething(), 60000);
  </script>
  ...
  <button type="submit" />
  ...
</body>
```

Following the post-back, a new timer will be created as a result of the page being re-rendered, how many timers are now running (assuming the post-back was within the interval specified by the timer)?

Comment: answer is simple it will be cancelled, only from server side timers can be maintained like in java quartz scheduling api

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It'll be automatically cancelled. JavaScript code is executed within the context of a page.

Think about a *page* like an *application*. Switching to other page is like closing an application and opening a new one. This also applies to a full page refresh (i.e. when you press <kbd>F5</kbd>).

Comment: Thank you for your answer; I have expanded the question though to more accurately represent the scenario and wonder if you have any more to add?

Comment: @MartinRobins I won't modify the answer. It already answers your update. A full post-back is a full page refresh, and I've explained what happens when you perform a <kbd>F5</kbd> :D